# WinForms WebBrowser control ignores referrer

Tags: c#, winforms, http, http-headers

I've encountered the following problem:

```
var browser = new WebBrowser();
var header = "Referer: http://testref.com\r\n";
browser.Navigate("http://localhost/test", "_self", null, header");
```

index.html at /localhost/test contains:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script>
                $( document ).ready(function() {
                alert(document.referrer);}
</script>
```

and it says that referrer is empty, althought I'd specified.
Why, and how can I force the .net code to send the referer, which will be recognised by js code.
Maybe using 3-party controls will help, like GeckoFx?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by using GeckoFx instead of built-in control;

Comment: Good to hear you solve it yourself. But why do not you accept your own answer?

Comment: Because I can accept my answer only tomorrow, and this solution doesn't gives me an answer to question "why"